# Passing generic types inner class

Tags: java, generics, lombok

Here is following example:

```java
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Singular;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Builder
public class GenericsType<T> {

    @Singular("entry") 
    private List<Animal> list;

    @Builder
    private static class Animal<T> {
        T test;
    }

    public void main(String args[]){

        GenericsType.<String>builder()
                .entry(Animal.<String>builder().test("my object").build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Is there a way just to pass the generic `<String>` one time? Actually the inner class should already know its type.

```java
GenericsType.<String>builder()
                .entry(Animal.builder().test("my object").build())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a limitation of the Java compiler. Although it looks obvious in this case that the type parameter must be `String`, inferring that is not as easy as it seems to be:
The compiler has to propagate the type information backwards from `build()` via `test("my object")` to the `builder()` method.

New compiler versions may support such inference, but at least `javac` 11 does not.